# CMake only copies files on reload, not build

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm using CMake in the CLion IDE, and in my CMakeLists.txt I use the following command in order to copy some resource files into the binary directory:

```
file(COPY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res DESTINATION ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
```

This works whenever my CMake project is reloaded in CLion. However, whenever I just try to build, the files aren't copied again. How do I fix this? Am I using the wrong command?

Comment: This is by design. `file(COPY ...)` runs when cmake regenerates your project not when you are building.

Comment: So is there something which does the same thing as `file(COPY ...)` but runs on every build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `add_custom_target`:

```
add_custom_target(copy_res_directory ALL
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory 
        "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/res"
    COMMENT "Copy res directory to build tree"
    VERBATIM)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `configure_file(... COPYONLY)`