# CMake : softlink resource ( such as GLSL shaders ) or copy each complilation

Tags: c++, cmake, resources, shader

The simplest way how to copy resources from source directory into build directory with CMake is

```
file( COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/resources DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
```

however, this updates the resources in build directory **only when** I call `cmake`. I need something which update resources **each time I call** `make`.

E.g. now I develop some GLSL shaders. I need to change simultaneously both the C++ code and GLSL code, and I need **everything is synchronized each time I hit** `compile` or `run` in my IDE ( I use CodeBlocks with project files generated by CMake )

The simple solution would be to make **softlink** from source directory to build directory. But I don't want to do it manually (it would be by-passing of CMake and would make project more fragile ). Can CMake do it for me ?

---

just for completness, this is how my whole `CMakeList.txt` looks like

```
# ==== common header

cmake_minimum_required ( VERSION 2.8 )
project ( SimpleSimulationEngine )

if( UNIX )
    SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x" )
endif()

SET( AXULIARY_COMPILE_FLAGS "-w -O2")
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${AXULIARY_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET( COMMON_SRCS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/common" )
include_directories(
        ${COMMON_SRCS}
        ${COMMON_SRCS}/algorithms
        ${COMMON_SRCS}/math
        ${COMMON_SRCS}/SDL2OGL3
)

set( CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake_utils )

find_package( OpenGL REQUIRED )
find_package( GLEW   REQUIRED )
find_package( GLU    REQUIRED )
find_package( SDL2   REQUIRED )

# ==== Particular build target

add_executable       ( test_SphereShader test_SphereShader.cpp )
target_link_libraries( test_SphereShader ${OpenGL_LIBRARY} ${GLU_LIBRARY} ${GLEW_LIBRARY} ${SDL2_LIBRARY} )
file( COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
```

Comment: Have you checked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28533760/cmake-only-copies-files-on-reload-not-build)? Both its answers are fit for your purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide a custom target with you turn into a dependency for your binary `test_SphereShader`:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(
        copy_shader_files
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
        -D SOURCE_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
        -D DESTINATION_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} 
        -P CopyFile.cmake
        COMMENT "Copying Files for target: test_SphereShader" VERBATIM 
        )

ADD_DEPENDENCIES ( test_SphereShader copy_shader_files )
```

Using the custom target invokes a new CMake instance with a script file `CopyFile.cmake` which contains your copy command:

```
file( COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} )
```

This way the file is copied every time `make` or `make test_SphereShader` is invoked. You can even copy manually be calling `make copy_shader_files`.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to accept the answer after I tried it ... works well

Comment: In your code you are not using the -D SOURCE_DIR= . and -D DESTINATION_DIR= ...   Those lines can be removed. Unless you want to change the CopyFile.cmake to being more generic.

Answer (score 2):

I had a few issues with the accepted solution. The biggest issue was that it doesn't place the folder in the directory of the executable for certain IDEs, for instance XCode. This is because `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}` in XCode is not where the actual binaries are placed, they are usually one directory deeper in something like `/Debug/executable`. To get that directory you can use $ but it doesn't seem like that works in a cmake script.

I still haven't found the perfect solution, but I'm currently using Option 1. I will update this if I learn more. And if anyone knows how to fix the cons of Option 1 I would be very happy.

## Option 1: `add_custom_command` with `copy_directory`

```
add_custom_command(
         TARGET MY_TARGET POST_BUILD
         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory              
             ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MY_TARGET>/shaders
         COMMENT "Copying shaders" VERBATIM
         )
```

Change `MY_TARGET` to the target you created with add_executable or similar.
Also change /shaders to whatever the name of your shader directory is.
`-E copy_directory` should be left as is, since it is calling the `copy_directory` built-in function in cmake.

### Pros:

- Single command, no additional files
- Copies to the directory with the binaries in more IDEs
- Fresh copy every time the target is re-built. For Xcode it also works when only shaders change.

### Cons:

- When using `make` (at least on Mac) it skips the copy step if only the shaders have changed. Let me know if anyone knows the right way to force a rebuild in this case. Doesn't happen in Xcode.

## Option 2: `add_custom_command` with `create_symlink`

```
add_custom_command(
         TARGET MY_TARGET POST_BUILD
         COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E create_symlink              
             ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/shaders $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MY_TARGET>/shaders
         COMMENT "Creating symlink to shader directory" VERBATIM
         )
```

Change `MY_TARGET` to the target you created with add_executable or similar.
Also change /shaders to whatever the name of your shader directory is.
`-E create_symlink` should be left as is, since it is calling the `create_symlink` built-in function in cmake.

### Pros:

- Single target based command
- Since it creates a symlink to the shader/asset folder any change to a shader is immediately observed without the need to rebuild at all. Could potentially move this to some other cmake command that only does it on first cmake invocation

### Cons:

- **WARNING:** This supposedly **does not work on Windows**
- While it works well for unix-based development, make sure you don't end up trying to ship something with a symbolic link to a folder your user won't have.

Comment: Thanks a ton this is one of the best answers